# What are traditional Jewish symbols of fertility?

Tags: children-parenting, symbols-symbology

What are some traditional Jewish symbols of fertility? (with biblical, talmudic, medrashic or kabbalistic sources)

Specifically, I am wondering what ideas/things are associated with fertility and increase.

Some examples I can think of off the top of my head:

- Fish - From Jacob's blessing to Ephraim & Menashe
- Grapes - From all the songs people sing at weddings, there must be a source
- Dudaim - Implied from Reuven's behavior
- Sand / Stars - From G-ds blessing to Abraham
- Fruit ("Be Fruitful and multiply")

I happen to be designing an invitation and wanted to add some imagery that I can back with sources, but also am genuinely curious.

Comment: What would be the purpose?

Comment: dudaim (jasmine or mandrake, depending on the translation)

Comment: @ethanpil Downvote because there is not enough information on what you're asking. Are you looking for some sort of kabbalistic "symbol" to bring fertility because I don't think that exists (because that's creepy and reeks of Avodah Zarah.) Or are you talking about signs that show you are fertile? Please clarify.

Comment: Jasmin  "Dudaey beni"
please ethanpil explain what you search. Give examples that you know in as non-Jewish symbols or the type of symbolicity you search. Do you want to compare cultures? search antic similarities?

Comment: Eagle stones!!!

Comment: Added some more info to clarify.

Comment: @ethanpil What's the context for your question (e.g., are you looking for a piece of art to give a newlywed couple, or something like that)?

Comment: @crmdgn I happen to be designing an invitation and wanted to add some imagery that I can back with sources, but also am genuinely curious.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with pomegranates (see below), or fruit generally, as you mentioned. Fish as a religious symbol has been co-opted by Christianity, so I wouldn't go that route, and sand/stars seems more nationalistic than familial (i.e., it's about increase in the tribal population instead of the nuclear family, which I'm inferring is what you want). And the lulav/etrog is pretty specific to Sukkot.

Answer (score 0):

[Pomegranates](http://www.jewishledger.com/2010/09/the-pomegranate-a-rosh-hashanah-symbol/), for a start. And also the [lulav and etrog](http://ejmmm2007.blogspot.com/2007/10/four-species.html).